Feeling disrespected by colleagues
I’m part of a team of six, including our lead and one new hire. While we primarily work independently, we collaborate regularly throughout the week. It’s a data analysis role, and we’re all experienced professionals. We follow a structured review process for our projects, utilizing a platform similar to Bitbucket for peer reviews.
About three years ago, I implemented a change to our data processing algorithm. The intention was to help our clients identify and avoid a frequent error in their datasets. This adjustment significantly reduced the incidence of that error. Recently, the new team member identified a potential flaw in that algorithm and raised it through a pull request.
Initially, I was hesitant about the necessity of altering my previous work, but I remained open-minded, recognizing that improvements are always possible. After some discussion, we reviewed the changes and merged them efficiently.
The following day, I noticed another pull request from the new hire proposing to eliminate the entire section of code. They expressed that they believed the feature was unnecessary and suggested documenting the process instead. I didn’t oppose this idea but inquired about their reasoning. My concern was that the existing checks had already proven helpful in streamlining user experience.
Shortly after, I was invited to a video meeting with the new hire and our tech lead to discuss the pull request. To my surprise, instead of addressing another topic we had on the agenda, they announced that it was decided the algorithm was redundant and would be replaced by documentation. I raised several points: we had invested time in developing that algorithm, it had effectively reduced client support requests over the years, and it was created for a specific purpose. They countered with arguments, including the impending discontinuation of the software that runs our processes. I didn’t want to create friction, especially with the tech lead present, so I didn’t press further. I could sense that my concerns weren’t influencing the decision.
Although I’m not particularly attached to the code itself, it felt dismissive to see it removed without a thorough discussion. It seemed the two of them might have conferred privately prior to the meeting, which led to the decision being presented as a foregone conclusion.
During the conversation, I suggested it would be beneficial for the team to openly address any questions regarding pull requests going forward. However, instead of engaging in a discussion, the tech lead approved the changes, and the new developer merged them right away. When I brought up my thoughts, they mentioned they had been waiting for my feedback for two hours, even though less than an hour had passed since my initial comment.
Ultimately, I felt disheartened. It seemed unnecessary to have behind-the-scenes discussions that sidestepped open dialogue. In our field, we typically value transparency and let the best ideas prevail. I’m no stranger to being wrong; in fact, I welcome constructive criticism. But in this case, the reasoning felt more like a decision made in isolation rather than based on technical merit.
I want to emphasize that while I’m indifferent to the removal of my code, it’s not uncommon for code to be replaced. What I find troubling is the lack of open communication and the undermining of standard team practices. Is it unreasonable for me to feel disrespected by these private discussions and the dismissal of our collaborative processes?

"the code has saved us many support requests over the last 2 years " how do you know?

Consider not using your real name

Do I read it correctly that the fuss about this change started over 2 years after it went into production and the change itself has not caused any issues in the mean time?

@HectorRuiz - Was the individual who brought up the issues with the code, through the push review, the same person who ultimately made a convincing argument to remove the code? If they were, then your initial push back on their feedback to improve the code, might have had something to do with their ability to argue the code required more time to cook.

@BartvanIngenSchenau - "I made a change to a script that we have about 2.5 years ago." - Yes. You are reading the code in question was added more than 2.5 years ago, and I presume, removed recently but I am not entirely confident that is the case.

@HectorRuiz - We are talking about code that is 2.5 years old? "The new developer spotted a problem with this section of code and brought it to my attention via a github pull request. I questioned the need for the change", so did you ultimately address their concerns, because you questioned the need to change the code and then in a short amount of time, 2.5 year old code was removed. My initial thought is the fact this developer, new to the team, able to convince multiple people the code needed to be removed for some reason. So what was that reason?

@HectorRuiz What did your manager say when you debriefed him/her?

@HectorRuiz - That was the only reason and it had nothing to do with the problem that was identified?

Does the tech lead have higher rank, power, or authority than you in the team ? If yes, then, I would suggest that you follow his decision. It's not worth arguing about it for this particular issue.

Wait for customers complaining. If they do, “I told you so”. If not, you were wrong.

With a mature or maturing product, updating to remove support calls is very important. Anyone that has stayed at a company long enough to take a product that far into its life understands the value of coding away support calls.
Rather that taking it personally, focus on educating why something should be done. If you did something to reduce support calls, and it worked - THAT IS THE MEASUREMENT.
Anything done to replace what you did must be as good are better at reducing the specific type of support call.
That is the question to ask. If X Support Calls times Y Minutes each year can be eliminated, how much was saved?
If you keep your discussion at this level it is pure logic and math. If they come up with something better - Great. If it is who said what when and hurt feelings, everyone loses and no one wins.
Think of it this way, the company had a solution in place to save $10,000 a year and client frustration. It was removed and a note was put in the Wiki. Does that make sense to anyone?
I am obviously guessing at the number, but the idea is clear.

Some people make a living by pooping on other peoples work.  We have one in our team too.
Its one of the ways to get ahead in a toxic (or soon to become toxic) workplace. You can't take it personally as ultimately it is "for the good of the company" but it is frustrating.  Best thing you can do is try to make the most of it, learn from the experience and become a better engineer.
PS:
Sorry about the language I thought long and hard and there simply isnt another way to put it.

@HectorRuiz - It really seems you are taking the removal of the code way to personally.  What you describe is a situation where a developer discovered a problem with 2.5 year old code, and went to their management, who ultimately made the decision to remove it.

@HectorRuiz - Consider the point of view of this other developer who came to you with a discovered problem and you pushed back fixing it, “I questioned the need for the change but was supportive”. I probably wouldn’t come back to a developer that questioned why a problem should be fixed with code that I discovered

Yes, it's just a new dev jumping up and down trying to get noticed for minor things. 'Pooping on' is the correct technical & scientific term for the phenomenon


Is it unreasonable for me to feel disrespected by these private discussions and the dismissal of our collaborative processes?

No, that is a very reasonable reaction. You worked hard to solve a problem, the work you did produced the desired result. And then, rather quickly, it seemed to have been brushed aside with little feedback or consideration of your efforts, the impact of the work or the concerns you raised.
Perhaps your next question might be:

What, if anything, should I do about this?

Or something like that. After reviewing your lengthy post, I think there may be several positive outcomes from this that you might want to consider:

If the decision was correct, then you may want to consider that there is a cost to collaboration and transparency that is often overlooked - the time that communication and collaboration takes is not free.

This may indicate to you that your organization is shifting towards reducing these costs while, hopefully, not reducing effectiveness or quality. This is a difficult process because it is desirable to resist unproven changes. However, it may help you feel better if this is the case, since you can now be more proactive in aligning with those goals.

Perhaps the decision was the right one but made the wrong way.

If this is the case, like maybe the lead wanted to encourage the new hire to take "bold steps" to gain confidence, then perhaps you will see that and things will "go back to normal" as the "honeymoon" of the new hire and the lead fades. This is not such a bad thing, and perhaps there is more to their relationship than you know just yet. But a single deviation from your normally transparent and collaborative process should not automatically assumed to be the start of a pattern.

Maybe the organization is changing or has changed, and this is the first time you have really noticed or been impacted in a way that forced you to take notice. Maybe this change is just within your group, or maybe across the organization.

Maybe transparency and collaboration are a "thing of the past" in your organization, and you are just now "getting the memo." If this is code that you implemented three years ago, maybe this is an indication that you need to move on to another team or company.
You do sound intelligent and thoughtful, a valued member of the team for sure. But when things change, some people may not value those things or may not appreciate them in you. Hopefully, that is not the case of course. But the fact you have a fresh hire could be an effort to change the composition of your team in order to change not just the people, but how your team does things in general.
I am not trying to be an alarmist, but there are indications in your story and your tone that you are concerned about "bigger issues" than the one you write about. If this process persists and you continue to disagree with the approach, unless you can readily identify harm or damage due to the change that management agrees with, you may need to adapt - within the team or by moving outside of it.
It will take time to sort this out. You sound smart and resourceful, so just keep your wits about you.
Good luck!
